# Setting size of jzy3d chart

Tags: java, jzy3d

I'm drawing points on a 3d scatterplot in jzy3d. When new points are added, the chart automatically rescales to contain all the points currently on the screen. I have two problems with this: Firstly, that rescaling is not applied equally to all axes (if you have points at (0,0,0) and (0,0,10000000), the resulting scale will be something like (-0.5 to 0.5, -0.5 to 0.5, 0 to 10000000). The points I'm drawing are representative of a geometric shape, so this unequal scaling really distorts that shape. Secondly, the automatic scaling is such that *all* points in the chart are in view, but (in some scenarios) I want to zoom in on particular regions of the chart.

Is there some way to manually set the range shown in a jzy3d chart?